# Shadcn focus-visible after click outside still stands

Tags: css, reactjs, radix

Added dropdown via Shadcn but button keeps beeing focused after clicking outside of menu, shoudn't be like this!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azuOU.png)

[Before click outside or select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tc4o.png)

[After click outside or select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHe4H.png)

Tried to check Radix, Shadcn docs.

P.S.: Usualy after clicking outside of the menu, button shoudn't be focused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this with:

```
<DropdownMenuContent onCloseAutoFocus={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! re-posted here as well: https://github.com/radix-ui/primitives/issues/1803